# Storing JWT token in cookie

Tags: security, cookies, oauth, owin, jwt

I know this has been asked many times here but I am not able to find answer to my specific query.

Setup :
Auth Server : OWIN Auth Server
Resource Server: ASP.NET webapi
Client: JavaScript SPA app (Non Asp.NET)
Load balancing scenario.

OAuthFlow : Implicit Grant

Question: When Auth Server issues JWT token, how do I put this token in Client's browser as a cookie?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't store it in a cookie use LocalStorage, if you support only newer browsers.

Comment: Isnt localstorage less secure (or not secure at all) ?

Comment: Check this https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Comment: Cookies are send with every request, localstorage is not, it's local. 
Cookies are used in CSRF attacks. Both are accessible via JavaScript, except HttpOnly cookies. But you cannot set Httponly Cookies via Javascript on the clientside. So better use Local/SessionStorage.

Comment: @Legends This is where the que is. when auth redirection 302 happens from auth server to the client, can you then put cookie in the client app? my guess is yes, the question is how?

Comment: So when you get the JWT token, just do the follwing to [set a cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp):
Example:
`document.cookie = "jwt="+YourJwtToken+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";`

Comment: response from server should contain the Set-Cookie header. Just make sure that happens rest will be done by browser.